# How to find the $n^{th}$ power of $M\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, for $M$ symmetric, $m\le 1000$, and $n$ arbitrary?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form, symmetric-matrices

I have to find the $n^{th}$ power of matrix $M$ which is symmetric about the main diagonal and all elements on the main diagonal are zero.
For example:
$$M=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right)$$

Here's what I've done so far:

1. I implemented matrix multiplication which have time complexity $O(m^3)$ and used fast exponentiation to find power of matrix in $O(\log(n))$ iterations of matrix multiplication. This has overall time complexity $O(m^3\log(n))$, which is very slow even for $m=1000$.
2. I find out about $n^{th}$ power of matrix on this website, which is related to eigenvalues and eigenvectors and Jordan normal form.

Now I don't know if $M$ as stated can be converted into Jordan normal form, and if so then how to find eigenvalues, eigenvectors, and finally how to use these to find $M^n$?

Comment: @Moo this matrix is sample matrix and i want to find for any matrix with given properties.

Comment: how to calculate $j^m$ efficiently

Comment: please it would be help how it is easy because i do not know very much about special properties of matrices

Comment: ... but a real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable, so no Jordan blocks needed

Comment: Any **real** symmetric matrix, that is.

Comment: @Moo I wouldn’t insist on a diagonalization via the eigensystem, though. Odds are, the eigenvalues aren’t anything “nice.” There are [other ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr) to diagonalize a real symmetric matrix that are nicer for computation.

Comment: i need proper steps to find nth power of matrix m which i can convert into algorithm for above properties like matrices